# Schematic on LT Spice

Tags: hardware

I want to generate sinewave by using Ad9833 and an amplifier on LT Spice IV but this Ic is not available,so how i can make this schematic to get sinwave? It would be great if anybody can help!

Comment: just use a AC sine voltage source (of course that way you don't simulate the ripples of a DDS but as much as I understand you that is not needed)

Comment: most parts aren't in the LT standard libs (even though there are a lot of parts in the library. To give you an idea of scale: I recall hearing something about TI having more than 1000 models of opamp on sale, not counting different footprints of the same opamp). Learn how to get spice models from manufacturers and use them in your simulation

Comment: This part is a complicated digital device, so simulating it’s actual behavior in Spice is difficult.  Usually, users of Spice will replace these kinds of parts with mathematical models of their behavior. What is the behavior of this device that you are trying to simulate? Curd’s comment is a good answer for you, if you just want to simulate the output of the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can import other vendors' SPICE model files into LTSpice. If the other vendor (you mention an Analog Devices part number) provides a Spice model, you can add that to your LTSpice library and create your own custom symbol for it. Then you can add it to your simulation schematic.

Wurth Elektronics has a really nice hardbound book titled "The LTSpice Simulator", ISBN 978-3-89929-258-9. There are other online references for LTSpice as well.